# How to reduce time to process data in procedure of mysql

Tags: mysql, performance, stored-procedures, macros

Thank you forum...please help me..
I have table which contain TagName and other table contains taglog  .im passing tag names to procedure called GetAvg which will return avg of all tags.it works well, but it takes about 35 sec to show 100 tag values.how to reduce time .please help me im new in database.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `GetAvg`(IN FromTime datetime, IN ToTime   datetime)
BEGIN
DECLARE  no_more_alarms INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE  TempTagName VARCHAR(45);
DECLARE  val FLOAT;
DECLARE  cur_tag CURSOR FOR
      select Tag_AVG from Report
      where(Tag_AVG IS NOT NULL );
      DECLARE  CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND
      SET  no_more_alarms = 1;


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tempAVG`;

CREATE  TABLE tempAVG (
val FLOAT
);


OPEN  cur_tag;

FETCH  cur_tag INTO TempTagName;
REPEAT

SELECT AVG(value) INTO val
FROM jas_taglog
WHERE ((TagId = (select TagId from jas_tags where jas_tags.Name = TempTagName)) AND jas_taglog.LogTime between FromTime and ToTime) ;

INSERT  INTO tempAvg(Val)
VALUES  (val);

FETCH cur_tag INTO TempTagName;
UNTIL  no_more_alarms = 1
END REPEAT;
CLOSE  cur_tag;
SELECT *  FROM tempAVG;

END
```

Answer (score 0):

You are manually implementing loops that could be written in a single query:

```
...
BEGIN
    INSERT  INTO tempAvg
    SELECT AVG(jas_taglog.value)
    FROM jas_taglog
    JOIN jas_tags USING (TagId)
    JOIN Report ON jas_tags.Name = Tag_AVG
    WHERE jas_taglog.LogTime BETWEEN FromTime AND ToTime
    GROUP BY Tag_AVG;
END
```